# number of all subsets of a set

Tags: python, algorithm

This is what I came up with to calculate all subsets of length 0, 1, ... , n of a set of length n with doubling single elements. Difficult to describe...

```
def subsets(seq, *args):

    seqstart = [[seq[i] for i in args], ]

    if len(args) == 0:
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            seqstart += subsets(seq, i)
    elif len(args) < len(seq):
        for i in range(args[-1], len(seq)):
            seqstart += subsets(seq, *args + (i, ))

    return seqstart
```

Examples:

```
>>> subsets(['x', 'y'])
[[], ['x'], ['x', 'x'], ['x', 'y'], ['y'], ['y', 'y']]

>>> subsets(['x', 'y', 'z'])
[[], ['x'], ['x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x', 'y'], ['x', 'x', 'z'], ['x', 'y'], ['x', 'y', 'y'], ['x', 'y', 'z'], ['x', 'z'], ['x', 'z', 'z'], ['y'], ['y', 'y'], ['y', 'y', 'y'], ['y', 'y', 'z'], ['y', 'z'], ['y', 'z', 'z'], ['z'], ['z', 'z'], ['z', 'z', 'z']]
```

What is the length of subsets(sequence) dependent on the length of the sequence? (I killed the process after 50 hours with n=14)

Thank You

Michael

**edit:** Thank you all. So it is the Binomial Coefficient of 2n over n.

To obtain all subsets instead of multisets (so a total length of 2^n) I needed to replace

`for i in range(args[-1], len(seq)):`

with

`for i in range(args[-1] + 1, len(seq)):`

Comment: These aren't really subsets. I guess I would describe them as sorted strings over an alphabet Σ of length at most |Σ|.

Comment: Try this one on http://cstheory.stackexchange.com - they specialize in this kind of thing.

Comment: No, don't; it's an elementary combinatorics problem.

Comment: @user: And why does that not ft on cstheory?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number of multisets of size up to n of a set of size n is equal to the binomial coefficient

```
/ 2n \
|    |
\ n  /
```

This follows by summing up the [number of combinations with repetition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinations#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) for k from 0 to n.

For n=14, this yields 40116600 multisets.

Comment: I'm not sure, but maxima evaluates `sum(binomial(n+i-1,n-1), i, 0, n)` to `binomial(2 n, n) - 1`. Where does this `-1` come from?

Comment: @phimuemue: Maybe a bug in maxima?  Just compare `binomial(1, 1) + binomial(2, 1) + binomial(3, 1)` to `binomial(4, 2)` to see that at least in this special case my summation is right and maxima's summation is wrong.  Or do the summation yourself (use something like Vandermonde's identity, should be on Wilipedia).

Answer (score 1):

For a given set A with N number of elements, the number of subsets is equal to 2^N

Comment: That's the number of subsets, not the number of multisubsets.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: True, however the question was formulated about subsets not multisubsets so I did not account for duplicate elements.

Comment: The question used the word "subset" incorrectly, but it includes code and examples, so there is no room for doubt.

Answer (score 0):

A number of (normal) subsets of a set is 2^N

A number of subsets of length K, with duplication, is N^K. Think of your elements like digits of some number system. If N is 10 then your elements are simply digits 0..9.

If you want the size of subset-with-duplication to be any from 1 to N, then there will be N^1+N^2+N^3+...+N^N sets.

Comment: Note that `n^1 + n^2 + ... n^n = (n^(n+1)-1)/(n-1)` (geometric series), but this solution counts e.g. `x,x,y` and `y,x,x` and `x,y,x` as three elements, while the questioner interprets these three as one!

Comment: Oups, indeed. I have missed that.